# Show custom meta on woocommerce product page if user role equals

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to show some meta fields on the product page only for specific user role

meta field= hiddencode
user role= hiddenrole

I tried this

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( in_array( 'hiddenrole', (array) $user->roles ) ) {

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'showhidden', 6 );
function showhidden(){
    global $product;
    echo 'Code: ' . $product->get_meta(hiddencode);}
    
}
```

with no luck

Im using the code snippets plugin - any suggestions?

Thank you :)

Comment: Looks like you have a typo there: `$product->get_meta(hiddencode);` should be `$product->get_meta('hiddencode');`

Answer (score 1):

Move the if statement inside the function.

```
function showhidden(){

  if (!in_array('hiddenrole', wp_get_current_user()->roles)) {
    return;
  }

  global $product;
  echo 'Code: ' . $product->get_meta('hiddencode');
    
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'showhidden', 6 );
```